# regression coefficient

Tags: regression

Consider observations on three variables X1;X2 and X3: Suppose that
X1 is regressed on X2: When the residual of the above regression is
regressed on X3; the regression coefficient of X3 is b3: When X1 is
regressed on X2 and X3 simultaneously, the regression coefficient of
X3 is b3* :
(a) Show that |b3|<=|b3*|.

(b) When does the equality hold in (a)?

So I get that X1=a1+b2X2+e;
e=a2+b3X3+e1;
therefore, X1=a1+a2+b2X2+b3X3+e1;
again, X1=a3+b2*X2+b3*X3+e2

Now how to proceed?